# LINQ query syntax with comparator

Tags: c#, .net, linq, comparator

Consider this code:

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(filePath);
 var dataFiles = from file in files
                 where System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file) == extension 
                 orderby file.Length
                 select file;
```

I've been looking for a string comparator that will do "natural sort". Sadly, there is no build-in functionality for this common task. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp) and it looks good.

Can I use NaturalStringComparer with **LINQ query syntax**? I am aware of the solution with lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible since the overload of `OrderBy` with a custom comparer is not supported in query syntax - only method syntax makes it accessible:

```
var comparer = new NaturalStringComparer();
var dataFiles = files.Where(f => System.IO.Path.GetExtension(f) == extension)
                     .OrderBy(f => f, comparer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the extension method syntax:

```
files.OrderBy(file => file.Length, new NaturalStringComparer())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\");
        var dataFiles = from file in files
                        where System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file) == extension
                        orderby file
                        select file;
```

this might help you.